# How can I catch a command exit code for later, in a Makefile?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, make, exit-status

I have a makefile, with a test suite target, like so:

```
rcheck:
        foo
```

This shows the output from the `foo` command on stdout, and returns an exit code from `foo` which is handled by make as normal.

I want to add *something* to this target, to parse `foo`'s output without affecting the existing behaviour - that is:

1. `foo`'s stdout/stderr should be displayed on stdout/stderr, as before
2. the final outcome of the rcheck target, as far as Make is concerned, is whatever `foo`'s exit code was
3. stdout from `foo` should be passed to a second command, `bar`, somehow. `bar`'s exit code doesn't matter, and `bar` should not output anything to stdout or stderr in addition to 1. above (unless the solution means `bar` handles 1. itself)

What is the neatest solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not worried about the timing of data passing from foo to bar, and you're okay with a tempfile which will need to be handled in your clean target, then simply:

```
rcheck:
        foo | tee sometempfile
        -bar < sometempfile >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

If on the other hand you care a lot about timing then you could make bar repeat its input to stdout and try something like:

```
rcheck:
        -(foo; echo $$? > sometempfile) | bar
        exit $(cat sometempfile)
```

I'm sure there'll be cleaner ways, but the above came to mind.  (Note, both are untested)

Comment: If `foo` fails, `make rcheck` should fail. The first part of your answer doesn't handle that, does it?

Comment: I used your second proposal, although it's $$() not $() (the latter is expanded by Make as a variable)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a shell that supports the `pipefail` option (bash, ksh, and zsh do), you could do it this way:

```
rcheck:
    set -o pipefail; foo | tee /dev/stderr | { bar >/dev/null 2>&1; true; }
```

My ksh manpage documents that option as:

```
pipefail
      A pipeline will not complete until all components of the pipeline have
      completed, and the return value will be the value of the last non-zero
      command to fail or zero if no command has failed.
```

As opposed to the default behavior:

```
The exit status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command
unless the pipefail option is enabled.
```

Comment: @Gilles, thanks for the edit - I missed the requirement that the original text be displayed; I was picturing a filter program that manipulated the text before it was displayed.

Comment: Since we're piping `foo`'s stdout, shouldn't the `tee` be writing to `/dev/stdout`?

Comment: @Scott, `/dev/stdout` is getting a copy of `foo`'s output without us doing anything.  We add `tee` to the pipeline so that `foo`'s output gets written to *both* `/dev/stdout` (which will become input for `bar`), and delivered unchanged to `/dev/stderr` (which is still wired to the terminal).

Comment: OK, I understand why `… | tee /dev/stdout | …` is a bad idea -- because I figured it out; I'm not sure whether I would have gotten it from your comment if I hadn't figured it out on my own first. The reason is that, when `tee` opens `/dev/stdout`, it refers to ***`tee`***'s stdout, which is the pipe to `bar`. My point is that if the user says `make rcheck > make.out`, then `foo`'s stdout goes to the terminal when it should go to `make.out`. Therefore, this does not _quite_ meet the OP's requirements.